# IQueryable: Creating dynamically an OR filtering

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, expression-trees, iqueryable

I have a set of search criterias in this form:

```
 member  |  value  |  operator
 --------+---------+---------
 height  |   10    |    >
 height  |    2    |    < 
 name    |  Carl   |   ==
```

And I want to query all the objects that match any of these criterias.

Right now, I'm doing it by:

- building an expression for each one
  of the criterias
- concatenating every expression using an 'OR'
  expression
- building a lambda
  expression containing the
  concatenated expression
- passing the lambda expression to the IQueryable<>.Where() method

Do you know a easiest way to filter dinamycally an IQueryable collection using consecutive OR?

---

### BONUS Our solution:

Based on [IlyaBuiluk solution @ CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCandJqGrid.aspx?msg=3388166#xx3388166xx)

```
// The structure used by the new extension method
public struct SearchCriteria
{
    public string Column;
    public object Value;
    public WhereOperation Operation;
}

// How to convert the rules structure to the search criteria structure
var searchCriterias = grid.Where.rules.Select(Rule => new SearchCriteria
  {
      Column = Rule.field,
      Operation =
          (WhereOperation)
          StringEnum.Parse(
              typeof (WhereOperation),
              Rule.op),
      Value = Rule.data
  }).ToArray();


// Usage:
query = query.WhereOr(searchCriterias);


// Implementation
public static IQueryable<T> WhereOr<T>( this IQueryable<T> Query, SearchCriteria [ ] Criterias )
{
    if( Criterias.Count( ) == 0 )
        return Query;

    LambdaExpression lambda;
    Expression resultCondition = null;

    // Create a member expression pointing to given column
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter( Query.ElementType, "p" );

    foreach( var searchCriteria in Criterias )
    {
        if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( searchCriteria.Column ) )
            continue;

        MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
        foreach( var property in searchCriteria.Column.Split( '.' ) )
            memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property
                ( memberAccess ?? ( parameter as Expression ), property );

        // Change the type of the parameter 'value'. it is necessary for comparisons (specially for booleans)
        ConstantExpression filter = Expression.Constant
            (
                Convert.ChangeType( searchCriteria.Value, memberAccess.Type )
            );

        //switch operation
        Expression condition = null;
        switch( searchCriteria.Operation )
        {
            //equal ==
            case WhereOperation.Equal:
                condition = Expression.Equal( memberAccess, filter );
                break;
            //not equal !=
            case WhereOperation.NotEqual:
                condition = Expression.NotEqual( memberAccess, filter );
                break;
            // Greater
            case WhereOperation.Greater:
                condition = Expression.GreaterThan( memberAccess, filter );
                break;
            // Greater or equal
            case WhereOperation.GreaterOrEqual:
                condition = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual( memberAccess, filter );
                break;
            // Less
            case WhereOperation.Less:
                condition = Expression.LessThan( memberAccess, filter );
                break;
            // Less or equal
            case WhereOperation.LessEqual:
                condition = Expression.LessThanOrEqual( memberAccess, filter );
                break;
            //string.Contains()
            case WhereOperation.Contains:
                condition = Expression.Call( memberAccess,
                                            typeof( string ).GetMethod( "Contains" ),
                                            Expression.Constant( searchCriteria.Value ) );
                break;

            default:
                continue;
        }

        resultCondition = resultCondition != null ? Expression.Or( resultCondition, condition ): condition;
    }

    lambda = Expression.Lambda( resultCondition, parameter );

    MethodCallExpression result = Expression.Call(
               typeof( Queryable ), "Where",
               new [ ] { Query.ElementType },
               Query.Expression,
               lambda );

    return Query.Provider.CreateQuery&lt;T&gt;( result );

}
```

Comment: Yes, see the line: "Do you know a easiest way to filter dinamycally an IQueryable collection using consecutive OR?"

Comment: @Clicktricity: It's very weird that we've got to make all this to just filter a set of objects that match 'any' of the criterias. In the other hand, we can just use consecutive IQueryable<>.Where() to do the filtering matching 'all' the criterias. so that's the question, there is an easy way to do this? My question was not enough clear. Thank you Clicktricity : )

Comment: In terms of performance and ease of implementation how is this a better approach than using the Dynamic Query Library? I believe this way you have better control over the SQL output of your expression trees.

Comment: @Raul Roa: Yes, it'd be easier to generate these expression trees using the DQL. brilliant. this scenario is in fact almost the de-facto example of a string-based representations of queries. Thank you very much +1. may you post your comment like an answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of performance and ease of implementation how is this a better approach than using the Dynamic Query Library? I believe this way you have better control over the SQL output of your expression trees.

By [Raúl Roa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53797/raul-roa)

Answer (score 3):

If you have a fixed set of operators and a fixed set of members, then you can write this almost without dealing with expression trees directly. The idea is to create simple lambda expressions for various pieces of code (e.g. `Expression<Func<Entity, string>>` for reading property of a member and similar for operators) and then just compose them to build an expression tree. I [described the solution here](http://tomasp.net/blog/dynamic-linq-queries.aspx). The only problem is that composing expressions isn't directly supported in C#, so you need a bit of pre-processing (see the section about "expandable utilites").

Then you can store basic functions in a dictionary and select the right one (or a combination of them) based on what the user selects. For example something like:

```
NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext();

// A query that tests whether a property 
// (specified by 'selector' matches a string value
var queryBuilder = Linq.Func
  ((Expression<Func<Customer, string>> selector, string val) =>
      from c in db.Customers.ToExpandable()
      where selector.Expand(c).IndexOf(val) != -1
      select c);

// Dictionary with supported members...
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Expression<Func<Customer, string>>> 
  { { "CompanyName", c => c.CompanyName },
    { "Country",     c => c.Country },
    { "ContactName", c => c.ContactName } };

// Ask user for a property name & value and Build the query
string field = Console.ReadLine();
string value = Console.ReadLine();
var q = queryBuilder(dict[field], value);
```

The article also contains an example with composing OR or AND conditions dynamically. I didn't update the code for a while, so it needs some work, but I believe that [LINQ KIT](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx) project contains a version of this idea too.

Comment: Very creative Tomas, congrats +1

Comment: great post on your blog.  You bring clarity to the subject in very clear terms.